# Typescript interface: Structure of object depends on values of object in sibling property

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

Right now I have those objects:

column.model.ts

```
export interface Column {
    field: string,
    header: string
}
```

table.model.ts

```
export interface Table {
    cols: Column[],
    data: any[] //Not sure what I should do here
}
```

I want the data property to be an array of objects base on this model:
`{prop1: any, prop2: any, [etc.]}`
Where the name of those properties are actually the value for each `field` property the `cols` array.

Is there a way to enforce this, or do I just have to leave the type as `any[]` and document in comment or other way the way it should be used ?

I looked through the typescript documentation but can't find something that would fit the bill. I don't have hight hopes it can be done, but thanks to anyone taking the time to answer.

EDIT:

I found indexable properties, which somewhat helps as a fallback to what I want a do: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types

Comment: Generics could work for you here. Basically you could be writing something like `Table<{ 
prop1: string; prop2: number; }>`.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html

Comment: The issue with using generics like so is that I still can't guarantee that those props name would then be the same as the value entered for the cols property, so I don't feel like it helps much in that case

Comment: Where do the names of the properties actually come from? And do they really all have `any` type? I think what you actually want is `data: {prop1: number; prop2: string; …}[]` and use `field: 'prop1' | 'prop2' | …` (or better `keyof Table['data'][0]`) in `Column`.

Comment: @Bergi I don't know in advance what the field property of cols will be. It will depends on the table. I'm working on a component to export a table to an excel file that I can reuse in multiple applications so I don't know in advance what the fields will be or how many there will be

Comment: @Sleepwalker In that case, use generics in the library (defaulting the type parameter to `Record<string, any>`), as Fabian suggested, and still use `keyof`.